# Asp.net core, Adaptive card to return a formatted date

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Hello I am new to adaptive cards and coding in asp.net core.
Below is an example of where I want to format the date shown in the adaptive card before showing it to the user. However when I format the code, I was only able to return 1 value from the List of **AttendanceMonthlySummaryResponse** (it has **Date, InTime, OutTime and Workhours**) returning as a list which contains many records for a specific month and year.
How can I return all the elements of the month, right now I am only able to return just one value.

P.S: **FormatMonthlyAttendance** function is not used here, in the current way it returns all my data when a month is selected however, the records are shown in the full date format which is unnecessary and irrelevant.

```
public class AttendanceMonthlySummaryCard
    {
        public List<Attachment> Create(List<AttendanceMonthlySummaryResponse> attendanceInfo)
        {
            List<Attachment> cards = new List<Attachment>();
            var json = File.ReadAllText("cardtemplates/AttendanceMonthlySummary.json");
            
            
            var attendanceMonthly = new
            {
                AttendanceMonthly =  attendanceInfo 

               
               

            };

            
            
                AdaptiveCardTemplate template = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(json);

                var result = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(template.Expand(attendanceMonthly));

                Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                {
                    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                    Content = result.Card
                };

                cards.Add(attachment);
            
            return cards;
        }

       private object  FormatMonthlyAttendance(List<AttendanceMonthlySummaryResponse> attendanceMonthlyData)
        {
            if(attendanceMonthlyData == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
          
            foreach (var am in attendanceMonthlyData)
            {

                
                    return new
                    {
                        Date = am.Date.ToString("yyyy MM dd"),

                        InTime = am.InTime.ToString("hh:mm"),

                        OutTime = am.OutTime.ToString("hh:mm"),

                        WorkedHours = am.WorkedHours.ToString("F")
                    

                };
            }

            return attendanceMonthlyData;
            
               
            
                
                
        }

        

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code only. It looks like you have a loop that return right after the first iteration. The entire `FormatMonthlyAttendance` method is problematic and shows an attempt to cover up problems - you can't return an anonymous type so instead of creating a concrete class, the return type was changed to `object`. Oops. You want to convert the items in the list, but just use a `return` which returns immediately. The compiler already warns you that `return attendanceMonthlyData;` is never reached. Besides, what's the point of that call?

Comment: This entire method could be replaced with `attendanceMonthlyData.Select(am=>new {...})`. You don't show where that method is called though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the formatMonthlyAttendance method is called in the top like this, i did not enter it in the above code :  var attendanceMonthly = new
            {
                AttendanceMonthly = new List<object>() { FormatMonthlyAttendance(attendanceInfo) }

            };

Comment: Add it then. But this code is yet another attempt to hack something into working and doesn't do what you think it does. This has nothing to do with Adaptive cards or ASP.NET, these are fundamental C# concepts. You can't write a complex program if you don't know what `return` does.

Comment: In any case, all this can be replaced with `var attendanceMonthly=attendnaceInfo.Select(am=>new {....}).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for the help